# How can I display a 2D array with a certain char passed in to each array reference?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My main method intializes a 2D array of size[userWidth][userHeight] (userWidth and userHeight are scanner input values collected and returned through a separate method. I then need to display a 2D array to be a "blank map", with each array reference containing the char '.'. What I'm required to do: call the blank map method from the main method, pass the char '.' into the entire array and then display the entire array. I cannot change the arguments for the blank map method, which are:
public static void blankMap(char[][] map) {

How do I pass the char '.' into the array of userWidth and userHeight and then print the entire array?

CODE:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System. in );

    final int MIN = 3;
    final int MAX = 20;

    int userWidth = prompt(scnr, MIN, MAX);
    int userHeight = prompt(scnr, MIN, MAX);

    char[][] map = new char[userWidth][userHeight];
    blankMap(map);
}

public static void blankMap(char[][] freshMap) {
    final char mapChar = '.';
    for (int row = 0; row < freshMap[0].length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < freshMap[1].length; col++) {
            freshMap[row][col] = mapChar;
            System.out.println(freshMap[row][col]);
        }
```

This current code will print (for example, if the array is map[3][3]):

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Help, please! I'm a brand new programmer and need to figure this out for a class!

Comment: My post didn't exactly display what this prints. It prints the char '.' nine times vertically, so '.'\n nine times.

Comment: `System.out.println` will print a new line (As the method name suggests). Use `System.out.print` to print without a new line and `System.out.println` when you want a new line

Comment: Also, the number of rows in your array is freshMap.length. The number of columns in the row i is freshMap[i].length. You don't seem to understand the principle of a 2D array, or rather, of an array of arrays.